# How would I structure PrintNode() method?

Tags: c#, format, doubly-linked-list

Currently this is my PrintNode() method and its giving me

Transaction No:

Date   /////////////////////   Description ///////      DebitCredit/////     Amount

12345678: 2012/01/15 abs a 100

And i want the values to be put into the correct places.

12345678 should be under Trasaction No:

2012/01/2015 under Date

etc.

How would I format it that way?  (Sorry if this is a horrible question. I'm still new at this), worked out the method, but I don't know how to "Prettify" it up.

```js
public void PrintNodes(LinkedList<Transactions> values)
        {
            if (values.Count != 0)
            {
                txtOutput.Text += "Transaction Details for Account No" + + ":" + "\r\n" + "Date\t\tDescription\tDebitCredit\tAmount";

                foreach (Transactions t in values) 
                {
                    txtOutput.Text += "\r\n" + t + "\t";
                    txtOutput.Text += "\t";
                }
                txtOutput.Text += "\r\n";
            }
            else
            {
                txtOutput.Text += "The Doubly Linked List is empty!";
            }

        }
```

Comment: You can use string.Format or string interpolation. See [link]http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/24/c-sharp-6-0-features/49/string-interpolation#t=201608230825425794575[/link] and [link]http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/79/string-format#t=201608230827059251396[/link]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet instead, and see the difference

```
public void PrintNodes(LinkedList<Transactions> values)
    {
        if (values != null && values.Count > 0)
        {
            int accountNumber = 1000001;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append($"Transaction Details for Account No. {accountNumber}");
            builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            builder.Append("Date\t\tDescription\t\tDebitCredit\t\tAmount");
            builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (Transactions t in values)
            {
                builder.Append($"{t.Date}\t\t{t.Description}\t\t{t.DebitCard}\t\t{t.Amount}");
                builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            }
            txtOutput.Text += builder.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            txtOutput.Text = "The list is empty!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the builder append do? Sorry for the silly questions :/ it'd just be good to know what it does when I use it haha

Comment: It is used instead of using string += "line" .. it doesn't matter if you used it or not, it's something to make your code more readable and organized.

Comment: The Account Number generates two of the same numbers, is there a way to stop this? I know of the .Distinct() method in entity framework.